# Why does this post have such a low score?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, specific-question

[This post](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3042/10-wickets-in-an-innings-in-international-matches) currently have a score of -7. I don't see anything particularly strange or wrong about it, but since I don't know anything about cricket I might be missing something.

**The OP has just stated he has no idea either**, and, in order to improve this site, both for him and for whoever happens to read it, I think it should be a very **good idea to publicly explain**, in a comment there, or in an answer here, why did this happen.

PS: of course "because 7 people downvoted", however I definitely expect the power users and moderators to have some clues about why was that downvoted, otherwise there would be something profundly wrong…

Comment: I'm likely just as clueless as you are about Cricket, but my crude estimation is that this was a [snowball effect](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/7103/how-does-the-2005-offside-rule-amendment-by-fifa-stretch-the-game#comment14934_7103) exacerbated by the ~8,000 views. The community has changed so much since August 2013, however...

Comment: My only guess is that at the time, research requests like this were frowned upon?  But I wasn't a member back then so I don't know.  Certainly on some SE sites this kind of question (particularly as it stood in the 1st revision) wouldn't be welcome without a lot of additional research done by the OP, but here, now, it's acceptable.

Comment: Thanks @Lohoris, even I am clueless what wrong with my question. It is much appreciated you raise this point here.

Answer (score 5):

No idea. This is a perfectly good question, and should by any reasonable standards have a positive score. The community has just got this one wrong.

I've upvoted the question and done some copy editing; hopefully that may encourage a few more upvotes

Update: actually, it probably won't get any more upvotes. Because the post has such a low score, it's hidden from all the normal views so nobody will see it. Shame.

Update 2: Hooray! The post is now "up" to a score of -3 and is appearing on the front page again.

Comment: now score is -1. Thanks for updating.

Answer (score 0):

The post got downvotes because of the content. You can see lot of edits in it.

People who are familiar with cricket can understand the below things.

The original post was about taking 10 wickets in a match which has been happened many times in cricket history(too broad to answer) that already mentioned in [comments](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3042/10-wickets-in-an-innings-in-international-matches#comment6031_3042). Then the owner of the post changed that question from test matches to any format of matches.

The answer for the question is simply `NO`. Even a simple google search will tell it. You can refer the given answer

> At present, only two players you have mentioned have taken 10 wickets
>   in an innings in any type of international matches.

that was mentioned in the question itself. The OP knew the answer, edited the post just to prevent it from closing.

The actual question is too broad and the edited question is not helpful to future visitors.

Comment: Could you please point out the [specific revision](http://sports.stackexchange.com/posts/3042/revisions) in which the question stated that no bowlers other than Laker and Kumble have taken 10 wickets in an innings in an international match? The question has always been specific to Test matches.

Comment: And the answer to the question is "yes", as noted in Bibek Rimal's answer. Sure, it's not a One-Day International (capitals significant), but it's an international match.

Comment: @PhilipKendall, I agree the answer is YES. I wonder how these records are not come under ICC records book while it's an international match. Undownvote the post and upvoted Rimel's answer.